# How can I add a ripple animation using CAAnimation in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, caanimation

I am trying to achieve a ripple effect in my `iOS` app where if the user touches a specific button the `UIView` ripples. I tried googling on this but the results got me even more confused. At some places I thought it was related to `CAAnimation`, then `CAFilter` etc. I could not find any decent tutorial on this, so if any one can help me, what code shall go in my following method. (It is called at the press of a button)

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
```

I need to know how can I achieve a ripple effect on the view programmatically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd imagine that a ripple effect is a very complex thing to do. Well beyond the scope of a question here, unless someone can point you to a project that does it for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the brave and strong (those who are not afraid of getting the App rejected):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rippleEffect" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:110 forView:myViewContainer cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationPosition:CGPointMake(100.0f, 100.0f)];
[myView removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Source: [www.iphonedevwiki.net](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIViewAnimationState)

Comment: Could you tell, why that might be problematic? Apple guidelines? Or some other reasons? Thanks!

Comment: @Agat because the transition effect "ripple" has never been documented, hence it is considered to be a private function / implementation and therefor should not be used according to apple's guidelines and according to the healthy coder's fear of imperfect upwards compatibility.

Comment: @Till it's not working.